# Taking Image backup of Windows azure server

Tags: azure, backup, virtual-machine

Im using Microsoft windows azure to host my Web application. I want to take a image backup of my server.

i have tried following procedure to take backup, but while taking backup my server is shutting down and even my server gets deleted.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/linux/how-to-guides/capture-an-image/

Is there any better way to take backup of my server without deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can snapshot the blob that backs the VM.  There's nothing in the portal, yet, to do this.  But there is a "storage explorers" that apparently lets you do this:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/17/windows-azure-storage-explorers.aspx